# Identities equivalent to the reflexive identity

Tags: universal-algebra, binary-operations

This is a follow-up to my previous question, here: [A characterization of the identities which are equivalent to the trivial identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750314/a-characterization-of-the-identities-which-are-equivalent-to-the-trivial-identit). As in that question, let our signature be that of a single binary operation $+$. The reflexive identity is $x=x$. I conjecture that the only identities equivalent to the reflexive identity are those of the form $t=t$, for some term $t$. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true.

If $t(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $s(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ are different terms in no more than $n$ variables, then in the term algebra of one binary operation, $t = s$ **doesn't hold**.
So it can't be equivalent to $x=x$ which holds in every algebra (in particular, in the term algebra).