# Equational identities equivalent to the associative identity

Tags: binary-operations, universal-algebra

This is a natural follow-up to my previous question, here: [Is only the commutative identity equivalent to the commutative identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747808/is-only-the-commutative-identity-equivalent-to-the-commutative-identity). As usual, let our signature be that of a single binary operation $+$. Suppose $E$ is an equational identity which is equivalent to the associative identity $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$. Must $E$ be an alphabetical variant of the associative identity? That is, must $E$ be of the form $(v_1 + v_2) + v_3 = v_1 + (v_2 + v_3)$, or its reverse $v_1 + (v_2 + v_3) = (v_1 + v_2) + v_3$, for three distinct variables $v_1, v_2, v_3$?

Comment: Yes. Apply the same resoning as in [the answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4747821)  + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Please define all non-standard terms, like "alphabetical variants".  An example is not a substitute for a clear, general definition.